# creating an appender with below java code programmatically ,I need to add MDC with my partternLayout

Tags: java, log4j2, mdc

Creating an appender programmatically in java with log4j2.xml
need to add MDC key variable with PatternLayout of Log4j2 ,
can any one look into below code and tell how to add mdc variable whose value will be replaced brfore the looger.info call

```
PatternLayout layout = PatternLayout.newBuilder().withConfiguration(config)
            .withPattern("%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level %msg%n").build();


final Appender appender = FileAppender.createAppender("target/test.log", "false", "false", "File", "true",
              "false", "false", "4000", layout, null, "false", null, config);
   appender.start();
   addAppender(appender);
   LoggerConfig loggerConfig = LoggerConfig.createLogger("false", "info", "org.apache.logging.log4j",
              "true", refs, null, config, null );
   loggerConfig.addAppender(appender, null, null);
   addLogger("com", loggerConfig);
```

Now I need that whenever my log statements are printed they  also print some value telling their state.

How can I add MDC key while creating above pattern layout ?

current behaviour of  ==> logger.info(" Here we are ");
is printing " Here we are "

My expectation is => statement should come with MDC key .

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern should contain something like `%X{someKey}` .

Then in your code, you would set the value, e.g :

```
MDC.put("someKey", someValue);
```

Comment: I tried using below pattern layout

PatternLayout layout = PatternLayout.newBuilder().withConfiguration(config)
            .withPattern("%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5{mdckey}  %level %msg%n").build();

But it is not printing it ..

Comment: It should be `%X` , not `%5` .

Comment: PatternLayout.newBuilder().withConfiguration(config) .withPattern("%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5x{mdckey} %level %msg%n").build() also

Comment: Try exactly `%X{mdckey}` .